# Greater than and Less than equal in for loop on swift 4

Tags: swift, for-loop

How can we implement <= and >= operations in swift for loop. i tried stide operations no luck.

Below is the option I tried

```
for i in 1..<=3{
   print(i)
}
```

error: use of unresolved operator '..<='  for i in 1..<=3{

Comment: Can i use  for i in 1..<(3+1){
   print(i)
}

Comment: You mean `for i in 1 ... 3 {}`?

Comment: yes  i wan the loop to be executed for '=' condition also

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for the “closed range operator”. It is spelled `...`:

```
for i in 1 ... 3 {
    print(i)
}
```

You can read more about it under [“Basic Operators” in *The Swift Programming Lanugage*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60).

Comment: And if you're wanting to do anything more complex, you can use stride: http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/func/stride/

Answer (score 8):

in c / java:

```
for(int i=1 ; i<=3 ; i++)
    print(i)
```

in swift:

```
for i in 1 ... 3 {
    print(i)
}
```

in c / java:

```
for(int i=1 ; i<3 ; i++)
    print(i)
```

in swift:

```
for i in 1 ..< 3 {
    print(i)
}
```